# Fleet management software/service C# and any SQL software

Tags: c#, sql-server

Good day. I am to implement a simple fleet(taxi) management software/service using C# and mySQL. I have done my readings and research but still I am having a hard time to how and where to start. Below is the qualifications I would like to implement:

1. A GSM modem (simcom 900d) connected to my PC via RS232 to USB cable.
2. An SMS with a specific format (name_place) is supposed to be received by the modem.
3. The sms data should be stored to database.
4. C# should be able to process and forward the "place" data only to another SMS capable device (e.g. cellphone) ---> or is there any way to do this without the need of C#?

These are just the preliminary tasks I need to do to start with. I just need a proper and good path to start off. Please help me and thank you very much in advance.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you need here. We can't just make the whole project for you. You should start with it and ask more specific questions.

Comment: I think that you could also consider using something like Arduino, Netduino, PIC or some other microcontroller.

Answer (score 2):

Start by defining some design for your system. I would start with

1. Writing down some use cases/scenarios
2. Draw some [sequence diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_diagram)
3. Draw [class diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram) for system
4. Maybe draw [ER diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-relationship_model) for database

After you know what you realy wan't to create, it should me a lot easier to start coding.